# Twilio Response from a non-twilio number

Tags: twilio

When my friends text my Twilio bot, Twilio responds from another number which is not even Twilio's and is named "SMSInfo". I expect the bot to respond from the same number. I assure you that I haven't set any logic there that a response should come from another number. Also, note that "SMSInfo" is a number which often sends them verification codes for Fiverr or other things.

Answer (score 1):

I just submitted a ticket to Twilio support and a bot automatically suggested me few articles. [One of them solved the issue](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181088-Why-do-some-SMS-recipients-see-a-Sender-ID-that-is-not-my-Twilio-number-).

> Sender ID change may occur when you send messages from a Twilio number
> that is not local to your recipients, for example using a US Twilio
> number to send SMS to Polish mobile users. This is often done to
> comply with local regulations, or to ensure the highest possible
> delivery rate for your messages.